# LocationManager: not getting updated position when device goes in sleep mode

Tags: android, geolocation, locationmanager, android-gps

I am using Android LocationManager in service to get the current position at reqular interval.
I am getting updated position only when the device is not in sleep mode or screen is off.
 If the device is in sleep mode, I get the same old position every time and when the devcie becomes active, again I start getting the updated position. Please guide

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html. This is the right way to do the things

Comment: I have to send the current location to server after 30 secs.
Tried similar way also but location not getting updated when device is in sleep mode

Comment: Which device are you testing on, and did you try any other device?

Comment: Yes, I have tried on multiple devices. Its not working on some devices like samsung

Comment: Can you share code, how you are doing it?